# A guide or layout for the Eleduino GPIO Extension Board Layout?

Tags: gpio, pi-3, breadboard

Does anyone have a guide or layout for the Eleduino GPIO Extension Board Layout?
It's a T Board but with 3v/ground and 5v/ground separated on the sides to match with the bread board side lines.

It seems to not match with the Raspberry Pi 3 B.

Testing with simple blinking LEDs, I've found that:

P7 (printed on the extension board) is GPIO.output 7  but P6 = GPIO.output 22

I don't want to keep testing by myself and maybe ruin my board.

How do I go about solving this problem?

Comment: I had a look here ... http://www.eleduino.com/Raspberry-pi-T-Cobbler-GPIO-Expansion-board-p10450.html

Wow ... what a strange board.  I think this is for some dedicated purpose.  I'd suggest go get a Pi2/Pi3 40 pin breakout board that exposes all the normal Pi pins.

Answer (score 3):

I ordered one of these and wish I got the standard Pi pin-out t-cobbler.  The pin-out diagram in the book is what is needed. However, it book was tiny and too small to use.  Website had no PDF so I went to the Amazon page and took a screen pic of the pin-out image.  [image: screen pic of pinout]

Answer (score 0):

The board is using Wiring Pi notation. Check this webpage to see the different ways the pins can be labeled http://pinout.xyz/pinout/pin22_gpio25

Answer (score 0):

Do you still have the little booklet that came with the extension board?  I ran into the exact same problem with this [kit](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01LYN8LPU).

I had the same problem with P7= GPIO 7 (BCM 4) but P6 = GPIO 22 (BCM 25).  If you have the booklet, the table on page 5 has a "Header" column in the middle with the correct GPIO pin numbers.  This table is laid out to match the pins on the pi, not on the extension board.  To use it, you'll need to look at the wiringPi values and match those with the diagram of the extension board or the labels printed on the extension board to get the physical location of the pins.  At some point, I'll print a table that is laid out to match the extension board and includes the "header" values.

The whole booklet is pretty bad.  I'm glad I didn't damage anything while figuring this out.  If they just labeled the extension board with either the pin name or the "header" number instead of that random wiringPi number, it would be a lot easier.  I'm pretty new to this, so maybe there's some use in that number that I'm unaware of.